# Run Word 2010 mail merge from access without query prompt

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, mailmerge, dde, word-2010

My scenario is similar to that described in [excel VBA to Automatically select Yes when prompted during mail merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301716/excel-vba-to-automatically-select-yes-when-prompted-during-mail-merge), except that I am running the VBA from the Access database that contains the data to be merged, and (this may be relevant) the Merge is using a DDE data connection because the Query is a complex one and is not visible in by ODBC. I am trying to run a Word mail merge from an Access Run-Time Application which will be used by people who are not very computer-literate, so I want to avoid confusing them with unnecessary dialogs. The Answer to the previous question does, indeed, work for me, by preventing the prompt to allow the query to be opened, and everything else happens as it should, but the Merge returns a "no data source" error when the procedure hits the .Execute line. It appears that the query prompt is indeed suppressed, but the query is not opened.

```
' open the mail merge layout file
objWord.Visible = True ' for now
lngAlerts = objWord.DisplayAlerts
objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
objWord.Documents.Add strInFileName
objWord.DisplayAlerts = lngAlerts

With objWord.ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = 0 ' wdFormLetters
    .Destination = 0 ' wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the dialog is bypassed, it is as if the user had pressed the No button. See Microsoft's KB article at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825765

i.e. your code will probably need to issue an OpenDataSource call before anything else, unless you can set the registry value described in the article.

Comment: I thought that was probably what was happening, but had not found the KB article you cited. While I could make the Registry change on my users' systems (the Application is installed 'properly' and the installer is signed and runs with the necessary privileges), I would not think it proper to change their global security settings to solve a 'local' problem. I did try the .OpenDataSource approach, but got a flurry of dialogs and errors. I will look at it more carefully and try again.

Comment: Adding back the .OpenDataSource call:
.OpenDataSource Name:=strPath & "NCMembership.accdb", LinkToSource:=True, Connection:="QUERY qryIRSReport", SubType:=8 'wdMergeSubTypeWord2000
again produces a flurry of dialogs and errors. After reading around this a bit more, I think that I am going to have to write the query results out to a temporary (probably text) file and use that as the Merge source document.

Comment: Yes, I understand about the global security thing. Unfortunately, in Word 2010, there is no VBA syntax that will create a DDE connection to a .accdb - at least, I have never found it. What does work is to rename the .accdb to a .mdb, but of course that isn't going to be practical in most cases. (But perhaps put the query in another .mdb that links to your DB - haven't tried, and probably also impractical). I may have one other suggestion but I need to check it out. But the problems seem to be enough that other people take the same route as you.