# How to select Yes in SQL prompts for MailMerge?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I've been trying to "bypass" the `Select From Sheet1$` alert that appears when you MailMerge a Word doc with an Excel doc.

I tried to save each document "without the data source attached, but modify the VBA code in each document to do the appropriate OpenDataSource" as stated in [excel VBA to Automatically select Yes when prompted during mail merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301716/excel-vba-to-automatically-select-yes-when-prompted-during-mail-merge)

But still Word asks for the Selection of `Sheet1$`.

Besides, the `DisplayAlerts=0` is not working for me. I'm guessing that just as @Ashton Sheets, "I'm having an issue with placement. When I have `wdDoc.DisplayAlerts = 0` set BEFORE I set `wdDoc = GetObject(wdInputName, "Word.document")` it obviously doesn't work because `wdDoc` isn't set. But if I put it immediately following the line it is too late because the word is only THEN opening and that's exactly when the message appears - so it's "too late" as stated in
[How to use VBA to say 'Yes' to any SQL prompts in word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801623/how-to-use-vba-to-say-yes-to-any-sql-prompts-in-word)

The idea of this code is to avoid any possible errors from users. Therefore the least amount of "clicks" from the operator is a must. Including `MsgBox`s...

It's also important to mention that I am using *Office 2007* to program this. And the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options` is not an option due to the several users and computers that will be employing the code.

Here is an example of the Code:

```
Option Explicit  
Sub wrd()  

Dim name As String  
Dim wrdapp As Word.Application  
Dim wrddoc As Word.Document  

Set wrdapp = CreateObject("word.application")  
wrdapp.Visible = True  
'wrdapp.DisplayAlerts = False                                                                  

Word.Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
Set wrddoc = wrdapp.Documents.Open("C:\............\3.2_CTO. A.FIN..docx")  

With wrddoc          
   '.Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone                                        

    .MailMerge.OpenDataSource ("C:\.......\3.1_Base de datos_FIN.xlsx")      
    .MailMerge.HighlightMergeFields = True  
    .MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False  
    .MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastDataSourceRecord  
name = Hoja14.Range("a2")  
.SaveAs ("C:\...........\Clientes\Persona Física\Cto. " & (tipo) & "# " & (name) + ".docx")  
       wrdapp.Quit  
       Set wrddoc = Nothing  
       Set wrdapp = Nothing  

Application.DisplayAlerts = True  
End With  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.DisplayAlerts = False
```

DisplayAlerts is a boolean expression, not a number one. Also, if you provide a snip of your code, it will help all of us on SO troubleshoot better.

You can also try `.EnableEvents = False`. Typically this works for the "Save changes" prompt, but it may also work for your situation as well. Again, a code reference would help in this situation.

EDIT: After seeing your code, I would try adding this `SQLStatement` to your `.MailMerge.OpenDataSource` Object:

`SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM Sheet1$"`

Example:

```
.MailMerge.OpenDataSource "C:\.......\3.1_Base de datos_FIN.xlsx",_
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM 'Sheet1$'"
```

[Credit where credit is due.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357121/executing-word-mail-merge)

Comment: @SergioMendez See my proposed solution above. I believe it is because you aren't specifying where you want to pull the data from in the opened document.

Comment: I made the change you proposed. Now there is an Alert in Word that states `Error in the conection with the ODBC Excel control` Stating it is open in exclusive mode by another user or that it requires permission to see its data or write in it

Comment: Start Task Manager and make sure to close out of Word. Make sure `WINWORD.EXE` and  `EXCEL.EXE` are both not in your `Processes` tab. I get that error occasionally when building scripts and do not do an `Application.Quit` or something like that at the end. It will keep your application open and is especially tricky when using `Application.Visible = False`.

Comment: Most probably it has something to do with the folder each document is stored in. Just ran the code with another document while referring to a whole different address and it worked. Eventhough both have a ReadOnly attribute...

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know off the top of my head, then. You could try also adding the `Connection:="Data Source={Specify DB book};"` option to the `.MailMerge.OpenDataSource`, but I don't think that will do anything. I would assume declaring your data source once is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it.

The code ended up like this:

```
'After defining variables and opening word app and word doc:

.MailMerge.OpenDataSource "C:\...\3.1_Base de        datos.xlsx",_     
LinkToSource:=True, _          
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"

.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastDataSourceRecord    
.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument

.SaveAs ("E:\_...\Cto. " & (tipo) & "# " & (name) + ".docx")
.Close
 wrdapp.Quit
 Set wrddoc = Nothing
 Set wrdapp = Nothing
'Remember that you need to establish in the VisualBasic Editos
' /Tools/References/Microsoft Word Object Library in order to access
'Word VBA's references.
```

The reason why it wasn't working was because of the **ReadOnly attributes** in one of the folders the DataBase was located in. Apparently changing folders attributes isn't always that simple. So, for me, the **solution was to remove the DataBase from those folders and storaging it in a new one**...

I hope this might result useful.

Thanks @SalvadorVayshun for your help.